# What is a shared configuration? (Fedora)

Tags: linux, fedora, eclipse

What is a shared configuration? im using fedora 20 and attempting to run eclipse as root. i am advised against this as it will cause the "shared configuration" to no longer by in sync with the actual installation.

I dont know what a shared configuration is. what is it?

Can someone point me to docs on shared configurations in fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared eclipse configuration is a multi-user configuration. You can have:

- private install
- shared install
- shared configuration

[Eclipse doc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html)

Comment: To confirm i understand this correctly. the purpose of a shared configuration, is to ensure that changes to an install made by one user, are reflected appropriately across other local user accounts. Is that correct?

Comment: shared configuration will reflect install AND configuration to be the same for all users. Shared install only the installation and each user keeps his own configuration in his home directory.

Comment: but tbh... that doesn't work very well, not because eclipse doesn't work but because source code are not on the same place for each user so the projects fail to run all the time if many users work on the same project if the project is not shared on the filesystem too. That defeats many VCS purposes in my opinion. Maybe in a special case. I think better to have multiple eclipse installed (even for the same user - I have 1 configured for pydev and one for html for example)